# ¿Por que la variable "result" arroja 14?

Tags: c

Luminoso dia! Este es mi programa en c. Me gustaria saber por que la variable result arroja el valor de 14, según mi análisis, deberia se 13. Espero me iluminen un poco. Saludos!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int product = 5, result = 5, x = 5;

product *= x++;
printf("%d\n", x);
result = ++x + x;

printf("Product es igual a: %d\nY Result es igual a: %d\n", product, result);
return 0;
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ya sé por qué XD:

Resulta que como en la primer variable x se postincrementa, x vale 6.
Posteriormente x se preincrementa y ahora vale 7. OBIAMENTE, la otra x también vale 7, porque es la misma variable, (No se por que yo pensaba que valía 6 jajaj).
Entonces 7+7 dan 14.

Ejemplo:

- `result = ++x + x;` -- Esto da 14 porque se preincrementa y ahora la primera y la segunda x valen lo mismo.
- `result = x++ + x;` -- Esto da 13 porque se pos incrementa(Almacena el valor de x para la operación antes de incrementarla y usa el valor almacenado), ahora la primera x vale 6 y la segunda vale 7(Como ya se incremento ahora x vale 7)

Comment: Me alegro que te hayas dado cuenta. ¿Podrías mejorar tu respuesta? Recuerda que esto **no es un foro** y así parece un comentario o una respuesta que le darías a un amigo.

Comment: Que amable. Le agradezco mucho su respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Esto se debe al incremento en la variable resultado; el valor es **14** porque la instrucción se evalúa de izquierda a derecha.

Siga la explicación:

La variable `result` se inicializa con el valor **5**.

```
result = ++x + x;
```

> En la preincrementación, x se incrementa antes de ser utilizado en la
> operación, por lo que se agrega el valor 7 y luego se suma de nuevo a
> sí mismo, lo que dará como resultado 14.

**#1 preincremento**: *incrementa el valor antes de que la expresión sea evaluada*
**#2 posincremento**: *incrementado solo después de que la expresión sea evaluada*

El operador de asignación tiene precedencia sobre el operador de postincremento.

exemplo:

```
int respA ;
int respB ;
int x = 12;
int y = 12;

respA = x++ + 1 ;
respB = ++y + 1;

printf("%i a \n", respA); // 13
printf("%i b \n", respB); // 14
```

Funciona de la siguiente manera:

*#1 respA*

primero suma los valores y luego incrementa.

```
respA = x++ + 1 ;
```

*#2 respB*

Primero incrementa y luego suma.

```
respB = ++y + 1;
```

O también se puede incrementar antes:

```
int x = 12;
x++;
respA = x + 1;
```

en tu código, La solución es cambiar el operador a `postincremento`:

```
resultado = x++ + x;
```

Primero sumará x + x y luego incrementará en 1 más.

*resultado* `13`